# Question about mysql and php queries

Tags: php, mysql

I am fairly new to PHP and Mysql so I am having a hard time wrapping my head around certain concepts and I come to you experts for advise and answers.

Is it possible to retrieve information from two tables without relating the two with 1 query?  Another words if the two tables have nothing in common.  If so, what might the query statement look like?

Second question.  Say for example I have the following two tables:

table affiliates
id, affiliate_id,date,clicks

table purchase_log
id,total_cost,date_purchased,affiliate_id

Now the two tables have "affiliate_id" as a common relationship.  What I want to do is retrieve the data that will look like this in table format:
date,clicks,total_cost

the date I actually want it to just generate all days of the current month and the clicks are the clicks for that day only and total_cost is ONLY if they purchased something on that day if not, its just zero.

I tried everything and couldn't get it exactly how I want.  I have this query so far.

```
SELECT purchase_log.date_purchased, purchase_log.total_cost, 
    DATE_FORMAT(affiliates.date,'%m-%d-%Y') AS date,
    affiliates.r_clicks,affiliates.u_clicks 
FROM `purchase_log` 
    LEFT JOIN `affiliates` ON purchase_log.affiliate_id = affiliates.affiliate_id
WHERE affiliates.affiliate_id = '{$_SESSION['member_id']}' 
ORDER BY affiliates.id ASC"
```

The above will generate the date, but only what is logged and the clicks are correct but the total_cost shows the cost on every row which is NOT correct as it should only show the cost per that date and not on every date.

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I assume purchase log only has an entry when an item was purchased so you actually dont want a left join because a left join will return results when there is no matching record in purchase log... It should look something like this i think, but i dont have your full schema and some data to load and test.

```
SELECT SUM(pl.total_cost) AS total_cost, 
DATE_FORMAT(a.date,'%m-%d-%Y') AS date, 
SUM(a.r_clicks) AS r_clicks_total,
SUM(a.u_clicks) AS u_clicks_total 
FROM purchase_log pl, affiliates a
WHERE a.affiliate_id = pl.affiliate_id
AND a.affiliate_id = '{$_SESSION['member_id']}'
ORDER BY a.id ASC
GROUP BY date;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  May I ask if you sum the clicks won't that show the total of clicks regardless of the date?  Because in my DB, there is only 1 date and 1 id per row. and each time there is a click, it updates the click for that date only and not insert a new row.

Comment: OH if your incrementing the clicks then you probably dont need the SUM's... i assumed each transaction was a new row and an order total for that transaction only. You might want to post some of your scheme and the update statements you run on these tables to add "clicks" and "totals". Given what youve just said that query may be off :-) (Also i updated the query.. i forgot a key part of the where condition)

Comment: Hey thanks for the help as I spent 2 days trying to use what I learned from your code to apply it to my site but I am still not getting the result I want...If you could further help me, it would be great.  What do you need from me so you can better see what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Post your schema and some sample data, and what you want the finished result set to look like.

Comment: Ok basically I am trying to track the affiliate information.  Have a look at the table generated currently which is not all correct but to give you an idea. http://img89.imageshack.us/i/statscd.jpg/  I am trying to actually show all days of the calendar when this page loads and for each day show how many total clicks if none, just show zero.  But at the same time I want to know for that date was there any transaction associated with this particular affiliate ID, if not just show zero. If it has, show how many transaction for that day and the amount for that date.  Thanks again for the help..

Comment: Schema for affiliates table is (id,affiliate_id,date,r_clicks,u_clicks) and for purchase_log is (id,total_cost,date_purchased,affiliate_id)

Comment: @rick: I meant you should update your question with the actual sql for the schema and some sample data for both tables... this way we can load it locally and play with it if needed.

Comment: @prodigitalson Oh do you mean export the tables and attach it here? I wasn't aware we could attach files here...

Answer (score 0):

@Is it possible to retrieve information from two tables without relating the two with 1 query? Another words if the two tables have nothing in common. If so, what might the query statement look like?

You can use UNION